# have a rails app with UTC set as timezone; want to get Jan 1, 2017 at midnight for PST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to say if now is less than Jan 1st at midnight Pacific Standard Time. I thought:

```
DateTime.new(2017,01,01, 00, 00, 00).in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

would do it but it gives me back?

```
Sat, 31 Dec 2016 16:00:00 PST -08:00
```

Should I be using?

```
DateTime.new(2017,01,01, 8, 00, 00).in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
```

or what is the proper, Rails-approved way of saying a specific day / time in Rails for a specific time zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the timezone when creating the datetime, i.e:

```
datetime = DateTime.new(2017,01,01, 00, 00, 00, 'PST')
#=> Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:00 -0800
datetime.utc
#=> Sun, 01 Jan 2017 08:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: ahh... much more concise - now would that be saying Jan 1st midnight in Pacific Standard Time (ie UTC plus 8 hours). In other words, 8 hrs after midnight in Greenwich, England?